# Manually construct an AttibuteValue in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to create an [AttributeValue](https://rusoto.github.io/rusoto/rusoto_dynamodb/struct.AttributeValue.html) (a type defined by the `rusoto_dynamodb` library) in Rust, but I can't figure out how to do this from the documentation.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
let mut my_map = HashMap::new();
my_map.insert(String::from("key1"), AttributeValue::from("value1"));
```

This errors, pointing at `value1` and saying:

```
AttributeValue::from("value1"));
                     ^^^^^^^^ expected struct `AttributeValue`, found `&str`
```

I'm fairly new to Rust and don't understand this error message, or how to read [the docs](https://rusoto.github.io/rusoto/rusoto_dynamodb/struct.AttributeValue.html). I think perhaps I want to use `s` - but how?

Comment: It derives from `Default`, so you can probably do `AttributeValue{s: Some("value1".to_owned()), ..Default::default()}`. No idea if that makes sense in context though; the docs aren't clear what the *purpose* of this struct is. It *seems* like some wasteful form of a union, so I guess if you're trying to make a string value, you'd just ignore the non-`String`-related attributes.

Comment: https://github.com/rusoto/rusoto is in maintenance mode (means no more updates) i would recommend that you use the official aws-sdk-rust instead https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-rust here is a good link to get you started with the official sdk instead https://dynobase.dev/dynamodb-rust/

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thank you - that turned out to be the best solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AttributeValue` doesn't implement `From<&str>`, and it doesn't have an associated `from` function either. It only [implements](https://docs.rs/rusoto_dynamodb/latest/rusoto_dynamodb/struct.AttributeValue.html#impl-From%3CT%3E) `From<AttributeValue>`:

```rust
impl<T> From<T> for T
```

This is a "blanket impl" - all types implement `From<Self>`.

So, when you call `AttributeValue::from` Rust assumes that the parameter must be another `AttributeValue` and complains when you give it a `&str` like `"value1"`.

`AttributeValue` is badly defined and constructing it is a bit painful:

```rust
AttributeValue {
    s: Some("value1".into()),
    ..AttributeValue::default()
}
```

Alternatively, you can also go through `serde`:

```
serde_json::from_value::<HashMap<String, AttributeValue>>(
    serde_json::json!({"key1": {"s": "value1"}})
).unwrap()
```

(I was hoping that you could get away with `json!({"key1": "value1"})`, but no, `AttributeValue` really isn't nice.)